How to use apply() on DataFrame using a custom function?
I have the following Pandas DataFrame:
import pandas as pd
from collections import Counter
print(sentences)

the output is (yes, the column name is 0):
              0
0             A
1             B
2             C
3             D
4            EEE
...         ...
462064467    FGH
462064468    QRS
462064469    EEE
462064470   VWXYZ
462064471    !!!

[462064472 rows x 1 columns]

I have a custom function to check whether the content in the column 0 has a length > 1 or not (just an example):
def is_more_than_one_character(t):
    if len(t) > 1:
        return True
    else:
        return False

And I apply the function like this:
counter = Counter(sentences.apply(is_more_than_one_character))

I wish to count the occurrence of each string having a length > 1. Here is the example output of print(counter):
[(EEE, 2), (FGH, 1), (QRS, 1), (!!!, 1)...] 

but currently, the output is:
[(False, 460686058), (True, 1378414)]

What did I miss? I think I am close. Thanks in advance.

You could filter with str.len and boolean indexing then pass to value_counts:
out = sentences.loc[sentences[0].str.len()>1, 0].value_counts()

Or count everything, then filter the keys:
out = sentences[0].value_counts()
out = out[out.index.str.len()>1]

Output:
0
EEE      2
FGH      1
QRS      1
VWXYZ    1
!!!      1
Name: count, dtype: int64

If you really need to use your function and original approach:
out = Counter(sentences.loc[sentences[0].apply(is_more_than_one_character), 0])

Or vectorizing the function:
from numpy import vectorize

@vectorize
def is_more_than_one_character(t):
    if len(t) > 1:
        return True
    else:
        return False
    
s = sentences[0]
out = Counter(s[is_more_than_one_character(s)])

Or, actually, since you'll have to loop anyway, better use pure python:
out = Counter(filter(is_more_than_one_character, sentences[0]))

Output:
Counter({'EEE': 2, 'FGH': 1, 'QRS': 1, 'VWXYZ': 1, '!!!': 1})


thanks for your answer, but I would like to use a custom function (to return a boolean) instead, as the actual function is more than just counting the length of the value.

@Raptor if you want to use your function: Counter(sentences.loc[sentences[0].apply(is_more_than_one_character), 0])

You can also vectorize the function (see update)

Or, if you want a Counter as output, just avoid using pandas at all and go for pure python Counter(filter(is_more_than_one_character, sentences[0])).

You can make a mask to filter out all strings that are of length 1 and then use value_counts to get the counts of each remaining string as -
mask = (sentences['0'].str.len() > 1))
sentences = sentences.loc[mask]
print(sentences['0'].value_counts())

